# Pi 5 vs. Pi 4 and External HDD

Tags: usb, hardware, usb3, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, pi-5

If I lsusb I see my portable hard drives.  If I fdisk -l I do not.  More concerning, when I listen closely to the drives that are plugged in, I hear them cycling every few seconds.  I have a 5 amp power supply and both drives are USB-3.1.  I tried with just one drive and it's the same thing.  The pi is fully up to date.  What can I do here?

When I run fdisk -l it hangs after the SD card, where I'd expect to see sda and sdb

Both external hard disks behave the same when plugged in by themselves.  A thumb drive works as expected.  Is the USB3.1 ports really rated appropriately?

Tested both external HDD simultaneously on a Pi4 8GB and it works correctly.  What the heck?  Need guidance.

Comment: Still sounds like a power problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `fdisk` to "see" your portable hard drives. `fdisk` is a tool for manipulating disk partition tables. Use `lsblk --fs`.